# Resolve hostnames with t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can i resolve a hostname in t-sql?   a 2000 compatible method is preferred.  Although something that works on 2005/2008 would also be helpful.

eg.  If i have the hostname stackoverflow.com i want to return  69.59.196.211

Comment: I'm not sure this would be an appropriate function for a database to perform. Also, are you aware that a single hostname may resolve to multiple IP addresses?

Comment: yeah, i know there are things such as round-robin dns that will give you different IP's but i dont have to deal with that in the environment im working in.

Comment: Sometimes, when all you have is a hammer..

Comment: This is not really a database question at all. I think this could be rephrased as 'how can I do an arbitrary external work via sql 2005?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could use [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx) to execute nslookup and parse the results.  Seems like a really awkward thing for SQL Server to be doing, though.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'nslookup intel.com'
```

.. then you'll probably want to stuff that in a temp table and walk through the results.

You could also, if you can get access to SQL Server 2005 or 2008, build a stored procedure or function in .NET and do a simple call to `Dns.GetHostAddresses()`.

Comment: Completely untested, from the Forum That Shall Not Be Named:

CREATE Procedure xp_Nslookup
@ip varchar(17)
as
 
declare @cmd varchar(255)
/*set @ip = '192.168.100.1'*/
set @cmd = 'For /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2" %i in (''c:\winnt\system32\nslookup.exe '+@IP+''') do @echo '+@IP+'^|%i^|%j^|'+ convert(varchar(20),getdate())
insert into Nslookup exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
delete Nslookup where Data is null
GO

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server may block access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' as part of the security configuration. As a system administrator you can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' as follows:

```
-- Allow advanced options.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
-- Update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- Then, enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
-- Update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- Then you can go ahead and run ...
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'nslookup microsoft.com'
GO
```