# How to get IP address of server only from query in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to select IP address of server only from query in SQL Server 2005 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
```

Or:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'MachineName');
```

Or:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

Comment: I need IP Address not the name of the Server when I am executing
"SELECT CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address," getting following error
'CONNECTIONPROPERTY' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You can resolve host names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967684/resolve-hostnames-with-t-sql

Comment: I want ip-address of server not of the current client .I am not able to get the IP Address instead of it every where i am getting only server name....but i need IP address..

Comment: Can not you make a stored procedure which resolves the hostname and return this back, and call the stored rpocedure from the clinet ?

Comment: So that means if i want to know "the IP Address of Server from query which runs on SSMS of server" is not possible   ???

Comment: What do you get when you resolve the name using xp_cmdshell on SSMS?

Comment: I want only IP so that i can put that value in temp table...when i am using xp_cmdshell getting all the details ...

Comment: select Local_Net_Address FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_CONNECTIONS  WHERE SESSION_ID = @@SPID 
Is this right ???

Comment: When i run this i get NULL.

Comment: local_net_address is null when the session is connected locally

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the help of function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCurrentIP] ()
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IP_Address varchar(255);

    SELECT @IP_Address = client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;

    Return @IP_Address;
END
```

Comment: This returns ip-address of current client not of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found, I hope it helps you

```
SELECT SERVERNAME = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME'))   
,LOCAL_NET_ADDRESS AS 'IPAddressOfSQLServer'  
,local_tcp_port  AS 'PortNumber' 
 FROM SYS.dm_exec_connections 
 WHERE local_net_address IS NOT NULL
 AND session_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY LOCAL_NET_ADDRESS,local_tcp_port
```