# Grouping by the shortest common suffix in data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a list of FQDN's, for example:

```
www.bbc.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
bbc.com
www.bbc.com
www.live.bbc.co.uk
www.live.bbc.com
```

I'd like to group these by the domain name; not the exact full domain name, but the shortest matching domain name that exists in the data. For instance, in the example above, I'd like to group

```
www.bbc.co.uk
bbc.co.uk
www.live.bbc.co.uk
```

together, as they have the common "suffix" of `bbc.co.uk`.

The fact that these are domain names is probably irrelevant, but might also play a part in the solution - can anyone suggest a way of `GROUP`ing data together by the shortest common suffix?

EDIT: as requested, as an output I'd ideally like something like:

```
Domain       Count
bbc.co.uk    3
bbc.com      3
```

Comment: Why is bbc.com not in the output? Why are bbc.co.uk and live.bbc.co.uk different? What are you using to define "suffix"? You might be able to use PARSENAME but your question is sufficiently unclear enough to not be able to offer much help.

Comment: There is no "output" above; the three `bbc.co.uk` rows as an example of data I'd like to be grouped together. By "suffix" I mean the right-hand side of the string: in the example above, anything ending `bbc.co.uk` should be grouped together, as should anything ending `bbc.com`.

Comment: But what is the "right handed" side of the string? Is is the the right most characters after the last period, the second period? And yes you stated in your original post the example of what you want. From the 6 values posted what do you expect as output?

Comment: That's the challenge - as there can be one period (`bbc.com`) or two periods (`bbc.co.uk`); as I can't determine the exact format, I'm trying to match (or group) on any common endings. I've edited the question to add my desired output; the second code block is NOT example output, just an example list of rows I'm trying to group together.

Comment: That is longest matching not shortest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to bodge my way around the problem: I've introduced a temporary "MasterDomainName" field to the database, and I've updated it with:

```
UPDATE r1
SET r1.MasterDomainName= r2.domainname
FROM @results r1
LEFT JOIN @results r2
ON r2.domainname = right(r1.domainname,len(r2.domainname))
```

It's not perfect, but it gets me closed to where I need to be. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know how many suffix to add in your grouping, it will be hard.

Maybe you can try to group by the last suffix (after the last dot).
Then if you got result, add the next suffix and group.
Then if you got result, add another one...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same amount of *dots* if you first convert the domain type to an IP address using nslookup.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967684/resolve-hostnames-with-t-sql)

Alternatively, there exists entire databases with list of known domain names. [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/possible-to-download-entire-whois-database-list-of-registered-domains)